# Count Number of Ways

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-programming

Assume you have a fruit and some vegetables. You gain 1 calorie from eating a vegetable. You can eat any number of vegetables to compensate the remaining gain from eating a fruit or no fruit.

Find the no of ways in which you can eat to gain exactly n calories.

m - no. of calories gained by eating a fruit

```
def totalWays(n, m):
    lookup = [1,1,2] + [0]*(n-2)
    
    for i in range(3, n + 1):
        j = 1
        while j <= m and (i - j) >= 0:
            lookup[i] += lookup[i - j]
            j = j + 1
 
    return lookup[n]
```

for example, `totalWays(5,3)` should gives us 4 meaning we can have `vvvvv, vvf, vfv, fvv` instead it gives 13. I think instead of taking vegetable gain as 1, it is assuming all possible values like `3vvv,2v2vv, v2v2v...`

Can someone help where I'm going wrong ?!

Comment: Can you post the exact definition of the problem? Your specification does not mention how many calories you gain by eating fruits (assumed 3). Can you eat multiple fruits?

Comment: my bad. in `totalWays(n,m)`, 'n' specifies the total calories and 'm' specifies the calories gained by eating a fruit. for example, `totalWays(5,3)` - 5 is the total calories and 3 is the calories by eating a fruit. Only one fruit is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

If only one fruit is allowed, then you can either eat one fruit or eat no fruits.

a) eating no fruits

The # of results is `1`, as it is `v` `n` times -> `vvvvv` for `n=5`, etc.

b) eating one fruit

The # of results is `n - m + 1`, because you remove `m` `v`s from the previous case, leaving `n - m` `v`s, which yields `n - m + 1` ways to place the `f`.

Therefore, if `n` is larger than or equal `m`, the result is `n - m + 2`. For `n < m`, you cannot substitute the vegetables for a fruit, and the result is then always `1`.

```
def total_ways(n, m):
    if n < m:
        return 1
    else:
        return n - m + 2
```